# Nested try-except logging wrong exception

Tags: python

I have nested try except blocks that appear to print the wrong exception.

This is on python 2.7.16

```py
import logging

try:
    raise ValueError('1')
except Exception as e:
    try:
        raise KeyError('2')
    except KeyError:
        logging.exception(e)
```

The output is

```
ERROR:root:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
KeyError: '2'
```

But I would expect the output to be for the first exception as that is what is assigned to `e`.

## Follow up question

If I wanted to save the execution info from the first exception, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, self-answer here: It's only the execution info that is for the second exception. The actual message is from the first one.